# Loop while public void in class is false

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to work out the correct syntax to loop for correct user input while a class returns false.

```
validate.cls file

******DEFINITIONS and other code********

METHOD PUBLIC VOID isEntryCorrect (INPUT userEntry AS CHARACTER):
    DEFINE VARIABLE cLogical as LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
    IF userEntry = "wrong" THEN
        DO:
            cLogical = FALSE.
    END.
    ELSE IF userEntry = "right" THEN 
        DO:
            cLogical = TRUE.
    END.

END METHOD.
```

There is a .w file that accepts user input on Button click and assigns the FILL-IN:SCREEN-VALUE to a variable and then passes it the method in the class.

```
UserInput.w file

****class definition***
DEFINE VAR userInput as validate NO-UNDO.
userInput = NEW validate("").

****local variable definition****
DEF VAR windowInput AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEF VAR iCount as INTEGER NO_UNDO INITIAL 0.

windowInput = FILL-IN:SCREEN-VALUE.
```

But that windowInput needs to be passed to the method. This is where I am stuck.

I need the program to loop and keep asking for the user to enter the correct string while the method is false, but I cannot seem to work out the correct syntax or if I'm on the wrong train of thought.

My thinking is that I could use a DO WHILE  to keep looping with a counter to terminate.

```
****the incorrect code*****
DO WHILE userInput:isEntryCorrect(windowInput) <> TRUE OR iCOunt = 3:

     windowInput = FILL-IN:SCREEN-VALUE.
     iCount = iCount + 1.
END.
```

If this actually worked it would probably keep looping until the count of three and then continue with the rest of the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your class method needs to return a LOGiCAL value, and not VOID:

```
METHOD PUBLIC LOGICAL isEntryCorrect (INPUT userEntry AS CHARACTER):
    DEFINE VARIABLE cLogical as LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
    IF userEntry = "wrong" THEN
        DO:
            cLogical = FALSE.
    END.
    ELSE IF userEntry = "right" THEN 
        DO:
            cLogical = TRUE.
    END.

    RETURN cLogical . 

END METHOD.
```

or just

```
METHOD PUBLIC LOGICAL isEntryCorrect (INPUT userEntry AS CHARACTER):
    DEFINE VARIABLE cLogical as LOGICAL NO-UNDO.
    IF userEntry = "wrong" THEN
        RETURN FALSE . 
    ELSE IF userEntry = "right" THEN 
        RETURN TRUE . 

    RETURN ? . 

END METHOD.
```

Your DO WHILE Block will just work. However, in order to allow the user to change the value between the iterations, you need an input-blocking statement.

Very old fashioned would be:

```
UPDATE FILL-IN .
```

or

```
PROMPT-FOR FILL-IN .
```

When your coding style is more event driven (a WAIT-FOR Statement), you would not be doing this in a DO WHILE Block. You'd be doing this in a Trigger to a LEAVE event of the fill-in and just count to 3.

Comment: When userinput.w is a AppBuilder DIALOG-FRAME program, you'll have to go with my last advise. Instead of doing UPDATE or PROMPT-FOR in the look, you'll have to work with LEAVE triggers or CHOOSE of the OK Button triggers. When then validation fials, you end the trigger blocks with RETURN NO-APPLY.

Comment: @Bazilby Other questions better asked as questions. Not comments.